# Не могу создать массив numpy. Module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Не получается создать и вывести матрицу, пишет, что

> module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'

Вот сам код:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(a)
```

Comment: У вас скрипт случае не numpy.py называется?

Comment: ДА,ТАК,КАК вы догадались?

Comment: За 20 лет успеваешь наступить на очень много граблей. Переименуйте. Не стоит называть исполняемые скрипты так же, как импортируемые модули.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev переименовал,вроде на одну подсветку ошибок стало меньше,но код все равно не запускается(

Comment: Значит в нём есть и другие проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел ошибку,как было замечено @SergeyGornostaev,я назвал файл также,как и импортируемый модуль,в результате этого,я как бы импортировал "сам себя",потом после переименовки файла,все стало работать корректно.